# Project Euler #10 in Ruby. Three ways to sum primes below 2 million

Tags: performance, ruby, programming-challenge, primes, comparative-review

Question:

> Add all prime numbers smaller than 2,000,000.

The first method is done by deriving own `is_prime?` method:

```
# First Method
def is_prime(n)
    if n <= 3
        return n > 1
    elsif (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0)
        return false
    else
        (5..Math.sqrt(n).ceil).step(6) do |i|
            if (n % i == 0 || n % (i+2) == 0)
                return false
            end
        end
        return true
    end
end

start_time = Time.now
range = 2000000
array_of_primes = []

(1..range).each do |n|
    if is_prime(n)
        array_of_primes << n
    end
end

answer = array_of_primes.inject(:+)
duration = Time.now - start_time

puts "Sum of primes below #{range} is #{answer}. Took #{duration} s to calculate using my first method."
```

Second Method is using Ruby's `Prime.is_prime?(n)` method:

```
# Second Method
require 'prime'
array_of_primes = []
start_time = Time.now
(1..range).each do |n|
    if Prime.prime?(n)
        array_of_primes << n
    end
end

answer = array_of_primes.inject(:+)
duration = Time.now - start_time

puts "Sum of primes below #{range} is #{answer}. Took #{duration} s to calculate using my Ruby's Prime.prime? method."
```

Third method is the simplest form - by using Ruby's `Prime.each(2000000)` method

```
# Third Method - Prime.each
start_time = Time.now
answer = Prime.each(range).inject(:+)
duration = Time.now - start_time

puts "Sum of primes below #{range} is #{answer}. Took #{duration} s to calculate using my Ruby's Prime.each method."
```

All methods gave the correct answer, but the interesting findings is they have drastically different performance, as shown below are the outputs of duration for the computation from each method.

> ```
> Sum of primes below 2000000 is 142913828922. Took 3.694159 s to calculate using my first method.
> Sum of primes below 2000000 is 142913828922. Took 39.370195 s to calculate using my Ruby's Prime.prime? method.
> Sum of primes below 2000000 is 142913828922. Took 0.300214 s to calculate using my Ruby's Prime.each method.
> ```

As seen above, Best performing is using `Prime.each` method. I wonder if it already stores a list of prime numbers therefore it doesn't have to compute that long?

Comparing using my own `is_prime` method and Prime class' `Prime.is_prime?(n)` method. The Ruby method is taking suprisingly long time to compute the answer. >30s compare to ~3s. Any thoughts on this observation?

Comment: I'm not a ruby programmer but the principle is straightforward.  You are performing unnecessary work by iteratively applying `is_prime` to each number.  Whenever you need a list of contiguous primes less than \$\mathrm{N}\$ it is more efficient to generate a [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) than it is to iterate through \$\mathrm{1}\$ to \$\mathrm{N}\$ testing each number independently.

Comment: Thanks @twohundredping the wikipedia article about sieve is interesting, please take my upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You should use implicit looping (`filtering`):

```
def primes_below(limit)
    (1..limit).select{|i| Prime.prime?(i)}
end
```

### You should use the built-in profiler:

```
require 'benchmark'
puts Benchmark.measure{primes_below(limit).inject(:+)}
```